# How do I redirect to another website using Python Flask?

Tags: python, web, flask, redirect, https

I am struggling to redirect to another website completely in flask. I am not sure if it is because of the nature of Flask or because I am using the wrong method. I keep getting the error 'Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'website' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. How do I get across this. The code I have written with Python Flask is below. Would I need a status code?:

return redirect('(https://website here)')

Is there any other techniques. I have read about using the webbrowser package but it doesn't seem to work when I deploy my application to heroku. Could someone suggest a way forward. Thanks

```
 @app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    dataset=format(data)
    model = LinearSVC().fit(tfidf_vectorizer_vectors, y_train)
    new_complaint = dataset
    new_complaints = ''.join(new_complaint)
    print(new_complaints)
    values =model.predict(fitted_vectorizer.transform([new_complaints]))
    print(values)
    labelling=str(values)
    print(labelling)
    if labelling == "['something']":
        return redirect("https://www.google.co.uk/", code=302)
```

JAVASCRIPT THAT SENDS DATA OVER:

```
new_arr = JSON.stringify(arr);
     console.log(new_arr);
      $.post("/test", new_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a status code.

```
return redirect("http://www.example.com", code=302)
```

Comment: Sorry, I have tried that method, but it just doesn't seem to work. Same error occurring: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'website' (redirected from 'website') from origin 'local url' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Any ideas on how to resolve that issue?

Comment: Try redirecting to another site. This message refers to a lack in the header you sent. Is it working for other sites, but not for your desired one? In this case, please post your desired link.

Comment: Any link isn't working, even google's link - try this : https://www.google.co.uk

Comment: In my machine, it is working fine, please post your full code in the answer.

Comment: @app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    dataset=format(data)
    model = LinearSVC().fit(tfidf_vectorizer_vectors, y_train)
    new_complaint = dataset
    new_complaints = ''.join(new_complaint)
    print(new_complaints)
    values =model.predict(fitted_vectorizer.transform([new_complaints]))
    print(values)
    labelling=str(values)
    print(labelling)
    if labelling == "['something']":
        return redirect("https://www.google.co.uk/", code=302)

Comment: My algorithm is connected to an AI hence the vectoriser use. First of all I receive the result from javascript, after turning into string, I use an if statement to redirect to the webpage I want. However, it is only that part that isn't working. i have checked whether the if statement. is working and it is? I am new to Flask; was I supposed to return something back to javascript after sending it over to flask. Is that why the URL isn't working?

Comment: `@app.route('/test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test():
    data = request.get_json(force=True)
    dataset=format(data)
    model = LinearSVC().fit(tfidf_vectorizer_vectors, y_train)
    new_complaint = dataset
    new_complaints = ''.join(new_complaint)
    print(new_complaints)
    values =model.predict(fitted_vectorizer.transform([new_complaints]))
    print(values)
    labelling=str(values)
    print(labelling)
    if labelling == "['something']":
        return redirect("https://www.google.co.uk", code=302)`